# Find a connection between 2 variables when not all variables are known

Tags: regression, correlation, random-variable

Lets say you have a system which contains two variables X and Y. You know they are connected but you don't know how. You also know that the system most likely has other variables which effects it, but you don't know what those variables are.

1) is it possible to perform regression even though there are potentially more variables at play?

2) Could you potentially approximate values for the hidden variable Z for given values X and Y - then perhaps through analyzing the system, decipher what the phenomena Z is by looking at what features of the system take on values close to your approximation for Z for given known values of X and Y?

3) If so, can this process be generalized to a system with n hidden variables?

Comment: (1) is called "regression."  For (2) and (3), what additional information do you propose to use?  If you have nothing besides the $(X,Y)$ values and no theory about $Z$ (or whether it even exists), how would you hope to deduce anything at all about it?

Comment: The point I'm getting at is more - is regression possible when you have a complex system with hidden variables